# Fragment shows the activity's viewpager below

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to turn some of my activities to fragments to work better with the navigation drawer.

This is the layout for my main activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I'm calling the new fragment:

```
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

And what results is this:

The new fragment is transparent and inside the viewpager (below the tabs). I can still see the viewpager's old contents behind, I can still click on the tabs.

Wasn't it supposed to replace the viewpager completely? That's what I wanted.

PS: I can set a background to the new fragment to not see the old contents, but it will still be inside the viewpager..

Comment: If you look at the source code of `replace` in <a href="http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord.java#BackStackRecord.replace%28int%2Candroid.support.v4.app.Fragment%29">here<a> You will that it does not replace the existing views inside the container. It only replaces the previous fragments added by the FragmentManager.